# Why does an ADODB.Command Object throw - "Invalid use of Null: 'replace'"

Tags: sql, iis, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I have some code that was using an `ADODB.Recordset` object to query a MariaDb database. In my query I am using `coalesce` such as this -

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(offers_owner.description, offers.description) AS description FROM
offers_owner LEFT JOIN websites on offers_owner.website_id = websites.id LEFT JOIN offers on
offers_owner.offer_id = offers.id WHERE offers_owner.id = 401
```

and in my code I have this -

```vb
If Not IsNull(rs("description")) or rs("description") <> "" Then
    response.write "<p class=" & chr(34) & "clear" & chr(34) & "><br />" & replace(replace(rs("description"),"company_name",session("company")),"company_city",session("city2")) & "<br /><br /></p>" & vbcrlf
end if
```

This works fine, and outputs as need be.

But, as soon as I switch to using an `ADODB.Command` object, I get an "invalid use of null". If I remove the conditional `If Then`, it does not throw and error.

Any idea as to why?

Thank you.

I tried to limit the conditionals in the IF Then statement

Comment: What do you do when you "switch to using an ADODB.Command object"?

Comment: Why are you using `IsNull()`? A null and a DB null are not equivalent.

Comment: @user692942 They are in vbscript.

Comment: @GSerg I [know that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927714/asp-classic-check-for-database-null-value-in-recordset#comment65216465_38927714).

Comment: The Invalid use of Null error occurs when you try to assign a value to a variable or field that cannot accept Null. Means that it tries to get the value of a Null variable. You can only get the value of a variable that contains a valid value.

Comment: @user692942 Then why are you suggesting that? Using `IsNull` is correct for checking for nulls in VBScript, VBA and VB6. Your comment here and your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927714/asp-classic-check-for-database-null-value-in-recordset#comment65216465_38927714) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927714/asp-classic-check-for-database-null-value-in-recordset#comment65235806_38939731) are wrong.

Comment: @GSerg Guess [I've been doing it wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33254589/692942) for 25+ years.

Comment: Just simplify the null check `If Len(rs("description") & "") > 0 Then`.

Comment: @user692942 Bummer. From your answer there it would appear you have been confusing `Null` and `vbNull`. `vbNull` is an integer constant that [equals to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44123629/11683) and it has nothing to do with the special value `Variant/Null`. Concatenating `Null & ""` to get `""`, [like I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927714/asp-classic-check-for-database-null-value-in-recordset#comment132627762_38927714), is a just hack, which won't even let you distinguish between `Null` and `""`.

Comment: @GSerg Not at all, `vbNull` is a vartype constant. But how "null" is interpreted by different ADODB database providers isn't always equivalent to `IsNull()` in VBScript. It's far easier to just eliminate the need to check null rather than wrestling with different variants (`Len(value & "") > 0`). If you need to distinguish between `Null` and `""` then don't use this method.

Comment: @user692942 The `.Value` property of a recordset returns a [`Variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/variant-data-type), which you may see as a "typeless" result, but actually it is [very strictly defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-variant). It can contain the special values `Null`, `Empty`, `Nothing` and `Error`, but it cannot contain something that is sort of null, but isn't one of those. The hypothetical database provider could not simply put it there.

Comment: @GSerg In which case, why if they're checking `IsNull()` (as you suggest) is it still causing "invalid use of null"?

Comment: I believe I figure it out, or at least a way to get it to work.

myCMD.commandtext =  "......."
set rs = myCMD.execute


description = rs("description").value


if not isNULL(description) and description <> "" Then
replace(description,"xyz","abc")
end if

Comment: @user692942 `IsNull()` cannot and does not cause "invalid use of null". It is caused by passing `Null` arguments to `Replace`, of which there are three (`rs("description")`, `session("company")`, `session("city2")`). The last two are not even checked for null.

Comment: @GSerg good catch the session values could be null, again why I prefer to use `& ""` whether it's a hack or not.

Answer (score -1):

The way I solved this was to assign the value of the field in question to a variable, such as this:

```
description = myRS("description").value

if not isNULL(description) and description <> "" Then
replace(description,"xyz","abc")
end if
```

Comment: Saving to a variable cannot be the solution by itself, unless your recordset returns different values each time you access a `.Value`. It is way more likely that it is solved by using `and` instead of `or` and (apparently) string literals instead of `session("company")` and `session("city2")` which themselves can be null.

Comment: As @GSerg has said you have two session variables that you do not null check the likelihood is one or both of them are null causing the exception when calling `Replace()`.

Comment: I have control over all session variables and they are never null. Bottom line is it works as I showed up above. It throws an error when both and / or are absent.  If I remove the if conditional all together and pass the recordset value into the replace it works. It's the if statement throwing the error

Comment: As already explained the code above works because you've taken the source of the null issue out of the equation (the session values). That is the only bit you have replaced, so it stands to reason the issue is there. Double-check your `session("company")` and `session("city2")` session values as one of them or both are `Null`.